# How to know my top overall ranking

Tags: support, reputation-leagues, rankings

In my profile I see `top n% this quarter`. For some users I see `top n% overall`. How can I know my top overall ranking?

Comment: Click on the link.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, okay, but I it still doesn't show me my overall percentile

Comment: `100 * position / total number of users`

Comment: okay, thanks, total number of users are under `Total Reputation` on the right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: For the `total number of users` the reputation should be `200+` or `1+` in the `Total Reputation` grid ?

Answer (score 2):

If the percentile doesn't show you can calculate it yourself.

This is the formula:

```
(100 * R) / U
```

Where `R` is your current position in the ranking, and `U` the total number of users (take the number next to *+1* from the list (Total Reputation*).

For me that is (100 * 2) / 2214 = .09%